# Amazon S3 if object exists method issue

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using amazon [S3 PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/if_object_exists), i need to check wither an [object exists](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/if_object_exists) or not,

```
$response = $s3->if_object_exists($bucket, '/albums/Carcassonne-France/');
var_dump($response); //RESPONSE FALSE
```

But when is see using S3 Browser in firefox the specified object exists

```
$response = $s3->if_object_exists($bucket, '/albums/Carcassonne-France/1.jpg');
var_dump($response); //RESPONSE TRUE
```

but this shows True,  as i have **1.jpg** at the above location, but i wan to check the below if the specified path exists or not.

```
$response = $s3->if_object_exists($bucket, '/albums/Carcassonne-France/');
```

How can i check the sepecified path exists or  not ?

Answer (score 1):

S3 is a flat file system. There are no folders. There are simply filenames with slashes in them. Some S3 browsing tools choose to display the concept of "folders" in their software, but they're just pretend.

"/albums/Carcassonne-France/" returns false because there is not a singular *object* with that name.