# Checking if a object exists on amazon s3 using AWS api

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on the AWS api and having an issue with the check for existing objects(FOLDERS).
I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814058/amazon-s3-if-object-exists-method-issue) question and it does not help me because I am using the latest updated SDK.
I searched the SDK and found [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist) which should work i.e. `doesObjectExist`,but I am not able to find the function definition anywhere.My `s3.php` file doesn't have this function.[Here](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php) is my S3.php class.
Also I read that S3 does not support folder structures but just visually makes it look like its stored in a folder due to the **flat file system**. Now,if I have to search a folder `1024x768` on S3,do I have just check the root of the bucket? I mean like this

```
     $chkFileExist = $s3->doesObjectExist($bucketName,'1024x768');
```

I need to check if the folder exists and if not create it on the fly dynamically using the API functions.If it exists store the files over there.
I need help in achieving this functionality.Please can anyone suggest solution with their experience.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Are you trying to extend the amazon-s3-php-class library? it looks like a stripped down version of the official sdk... You might need to download and use the official SDK to get full functionality.

Comment: I am not sure,I thought so,but I couldn't find it on the web and the GIT link does come up each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to give a little more thought to the whole "flat file system". When I first started writing PHP to interface with the S3 API I was expecting to be able to iterate over a directory, and the files in each folder. That's not how it works though!

This is from Ryan Parman, one of the responses in a question you referenced:

"S3 is a flat file system. There are no folders. There are simply filenames with slashes in them. Some S3 browsing tools choose to display the concept of "folders" in their software, but they're just pretend.

"/albums/Carcassonne-France/" returns false because there is not a singular object with that name."

If you have objects with the following paths:

`s3://myBucket/myFolder/taco.jpg`

`s3://myBucket/myFolder/jambox.jpg`

If you check for existence of the object `s3://myBucket/myFolder/` it will return false since there is no object with that specific name.

It might be helpful to know more about why you want to create the folder if it doesn't exist, but if you want to place an object into S3 in a specific "folder", you can just use the `putObject()` method.

Comment: I want to store user specific images,like our FB profile does,so that I can populate the gallery on his dashboard and show it.If I store them randomly I won't be able to idemtify them on per user basis,or rather it would be more tedious!!

Comment: You mean to say I won't be able to do what I am trying to?? :P

Comment: @KillABug You should still be able to pull that off, you should still be able to use a directory-like naming convention too, it just won't actually have folders. My use case I had files that had to be processed and pushed into a database according to what "folder" they were in. Any files in my buckets still adhered to a directory-like naming convention: `s3://myBucket/pretendFolder/fileName.gz`, I would just look for the characters between the first `/` and the second `/`. Since the S3 web interface behaves like there are folders, I kept using the slashes instead of another separator character

Comment: @KillABug I'm starting to tangent away from your actual question. For your use here, if you have a completely empty bucket `s3://myBucket/` and you want to push a file into `s3://myBucket/myDir/MySubDir/picture.jpg`, you can just call `putObject()` and pass your file into the key of `s3://myBucket/myDir/MySubDir/picture.jpg` without checking for existance of "folders".

Comment: I think his biggest issue is using a partially implemented library. If you go to http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/ and downlod the sdk it comes as a .phar file that you can include or you can install the sdk via composer if you are so inclined. then check out this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html and look at the `Creating a client` and `Iterators ` sections

Comment: @Dan You mean to say,I should just pass the folder/dir name each time I want to store it there.`If it exists {it will add to the existing one}else{it will create the needed structure}` Right? :P ;)

Answer (score 2):

@Dan is correct. However, it might be worthwhile to check out the [S3 StreamWrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.StreamWrapper.html), which enables you to use PHP's built-in file system functions with S3.

Answer (score 1):

I acheived the same thing using below a simple `hack`. we have to include a file in each of the folder and can check for that file so if that file exists that means folder path is valid. In my case the file I took was **donotdelete.txt** so that any s3 viewer can understand that this file should not be deleted.Now check for this file using `getObjectInfo` function. For Example:

```
    if($s3->getObjectInfo("bucketName","folder_name/donotdelete.txt")))
    { 
        //Do Whatever you want to do if folder exists
    }
    else
    {
        //Do whatever you want to do if folder doesn't exist
    }
```

Comment: This is not a hack in regards to the title.